# Help with songwriting, refrain confusion

Tags: songwriting

I wonder if you could offer some advice.
I’m doing well with a collection of ideas for songs but am struggling to get them completed. I tend to use a lot of refrain instead of chorus so for example the verse will lead into an 8 or 4 bar refrain incorporating the song title . The problem with this is that I’m straight into another verse then refrain then I’ll put a mid 8 then either another verse refrain and end . And I don’t want this same format throughout all my songs. It has been remarked upon with my earlier work that the guitar parts don’t really change much and this needs to be resolved 
Any ideas on how to make my songs more intersecting? 
P.s my style is folk/indie acoustic (Nick Drake, Fionn Regan , Damien rice style ) 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to write songs differently from how you've been writing them? If you don't want to repeat the same words over an over again, you'll have to come up with more words. Is that what you are struggling with?

Comment: No the lyrics are fine it’s the song structure. I was always under the impression that refrain was different to a chorus as it kind of rounds off a verse rather than being a whole different section (blowing in the wind) is a classic refrain

Comment: What's not clear to me is what the problem is. Are you saying that all of your songs sound the same? Or when you "finish" writing a song it isn't the way you want it to be? It seems like the answer to your question is "just write the song differently", but I'm assuming you've already thought of that so I'm trying to understand why that doesn't help.

Comment: You need to listen and analyze other songs that you like.  Analyze Nick Drake songs and you will see how they flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refrain, Chorus.  Same thing.

Yes, you've described a very standard song layout.  It's standard because it works.  (One 'standard' thing that I suggest you DO avoid is having a long instrumental intro, or a sequencer-style 'buildup' before the song starts properly.)

Listen to lots of songs.  When you hear an idea you like, steal it!

Try two choruses (sorry, refrains) in a row.  Try a central section in a completely different tempo.  Try leaving the guitar out for a section (or a whole song).  Try having the guitar play only single-note lines.

Comment: Why avoid long instrumental intros?

Comment: @Dekkadeci Because people with a low musical boredom threshold will never get as far as the actual song, perhaps?

Comment: Because they're boring.   I know your composition technique might be to loop a drum 'beat' a few times, add a bass for a few more repeats, etc.  but we don't need to watch you doing it.  Hit us with the good stuff!

Comment: I think the OP is correctly distinguishing a refrain from a chorus as a refrain containing the one line that finishes off a verse as opposed to a chorus which is a full separate section. See their comment above about blowing in the wind.

Comment: "A refrain (from Vulgar Latin refringere, "to repeat", and later from Old French refraindre) is the line or lines that are repeated in music or in verse; the "chorus" of a song."  *wikipedia*    So I think we can at least agree that the distinction is far from cut-and-dried.